# Convert LinkedHashMap<String,String> to an object in Java

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I'll start directly with my question and later on I give more background information.

**Simple**: I hava a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` and it represents a specific object. 
What is the best way to convert it to that object?

I know that you can use generics to get through all elements and set the fields, but what is whit nested objects?

**Background**: I have a JAX-RS service that consumes JSON objects. My service handles different kind of objects and just represents an interface. So I don't know which objects are coming from outside and which program is using my service.

At runtime I get the information via `@Inject` on my interface. The JAX-RS service stores the data from the client in an untyped Object and its done automatically (thats the `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`).

With my interface I want to provide a method like `setObject` and parameter should be a object of that type. I can handle all of this, but not the part where I convert the Object `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` to that specific object.

**Example Structure**:
Target Objects could like that

```
public class Document {
    private String title;
    private String id;
    private int version;
}
```

The `LinkedHashMap` looks like that

```
{title=some title, id=1, version=1}
```

Comment: Have you Googled for a library to assist with converting from JSON to Java objects? You cannot be alone in wanting to do this.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `HashMap` instead?

Comment: What would be the benefit of using a HashMap @mercutio

Comment: @DuncanJones my problem is that I already have transfered JSON to Java, this is done automatically within JAX-RS. But at the point of retrieving the information I have no information about the later object. So having a Object that represents this LinkedHashmap is fine.

Comment: convertValue worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two classes

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Document {
    @XmlElement
    private String title;
    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private int version;
}  


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MapJson {
    @XmlElement
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> documents; 
}
```

and cobvert Object to JSON usingg
Jackson

```
new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(instanceofMapJson);
```

Google JSON

```
new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(instanceofMapJson);
```

PS. Using google json, you can remove xml annotations from your classes

Comment: I also thought about performing a reverse marshaling with the same method JAX-RS is using. I really like Gson but for my case I would like to have a JAX-RS standard way, so that on application server jackson or any other JAX-RS implementation will be used.

Is there a way for that?

Comment: I'm using Gson right now, but I'm still looking forward for a not library dependent way.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is the only way for setting properties of generic unknown object.
You can find everything you will need in the docs.

Comment: Hmm ok but how do I handle nested objects in a performant way?

Comment: Reflection is NOT designed for performance. You can try to cache object's (class) variable->method mappings in your (application containing) `setObject` method, it will eliminate the need to iterate over the object's properties/methods every time, but it is still going to be (relatively) slow. There is nothing you can do about dynamic method invocation - it **IS SLOW**.

Comment: Do you know if there is library out there that helps me setting up the object?

Comment: From the top of my head - try to look at JAXB (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+jaxb)

Comment: I tried reflection and I end up using Gson to map my object. Handling nested objects can be a mess...