# com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, moxy

I am sending a POST request create a resource named `ContentInstance`.

**Resource:**

`ContentInstance`.

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2

import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "stateTag",
    "creator",
    "contentInfo",
    "contentSize",
    "ontologyRef",
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "contentInstance")
public class ContentInstance
    extends AnnounceableSubordinateResource
{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
    protected BigInteger stateTag;
    protected String creator;
    protected String contentInfo;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
    protected BigInteger contentSize;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String ontologyRef;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Object content;

    /**
     * Getter setters         * 
     */
}
```

I send my resource object by converting it to JSON using JAXB :

**Client**

```
     ContentInstance cont = new ContentInstance();
     cont.setContent("Sid");
     cont.setStateTag(BigInteger.ONE);
     cont.setContentSize(BigInteger.TEN);

     JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {ContentInstance.class}, null);

            try
            {
                Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
                marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                System.out.println("Object=" + object);
                marshaller.marshal(object, sw);
                String jsonContent = sw.toString();
            }
            catch (JAXBException e){

                System.out.println("--------JAXB EXCEPTION------------\n" );
                e.printStackTrace();
                LOGGER.error("JAXB marshalling error!", e);
            }

      try {

         HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(jsonContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         ((HttpPost) httpUriRequest).setEntity(entity);
         System.out.println("ENTITY" + entity);

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

On service :
I retrieve the resource as `Object` type and I get a `LinkedHashMap` of the resource. I use `ObjectMapper` to convert this to my `ContentInstance` type

**REST Service:**

```
    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
        public String handlePostRequest(Object resource) {

        System.out.println("\nINSIDE HANDLE POST: CONTENT CLASS " + resource.getClass());
        System.out.println("\nINSIDE HANDLE POST: " + resource);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        ContentInstance container = objectMapper.convertValue(resource, ContentInstance.class);
        System.out.println("\n State Tag: " + container.getStateTag() + "\nContent SIZE" + container.getContentSize() + "\nContent " + container.getContent());
        return "Dummy Data";
        }
```

My SOP prints:

```
INSIDE HANDLE POST: CONTENT CLASS class java.util.LinkedHashMap
INSIDE HANDLE POST: {stateTag=1, contentSize=10, content={type=string, value=Sid}}
State Tag: 1
Content SIZE10
Content {type=string, value=Sid}
```

So my SOP is prints that it get a `LinkedHashMap` intially and then after conversion via `ObjectMapper` it prints corrects data. But in request validation I get exception.

**SERVER LOG**:

```
INSIDE HANDLE POST: CONTENT CLASS class java.util.LinkedHashMap
INSIDE HANDLE POST: {stateTag=1, contentSize=10, content={type=string, value=Sid}}
WriteValueAsString {"stateTag":1,"contentSize":10,"content":{"type":"string","value":"Sid"}}
 inside processRequest
 inside validateRequest
 inside validateRequestWithXSD
10:48:31,946 ERROR [common.utils.XmlMapper] (http--192.168.105.213-8080-1) SAXException error!: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
    at javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource$1.parse(JAXBSource.java:225) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource$1.parse(JAXBSource.java:210) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.validate(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:715)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:96)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at common.utils.XmlMapper.validateObject(XmlMapper.java:103) [common.jar:]
    at platform.receiverActions.requestProcedures.business.RequestValidationBean.validateRequestWithXSD(RequestValidationBean.java:77) [receiverActions.jar:]
    at platform.receiverActions.requestProcedures.business.RequestValidationBean.validateRequest(RequestValidationBean.java:33) [receiverActions.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:202) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at platform.receiverActions.requestProcedures.business.RequestValidation$$$view15.validateRequest(Unknown Source) [receiverActions.jar:]
    at platform.receiverActions.requestProcedures.business.RequestProcessingBean.processRequest(RequestProcessingBean.java:36) [receiverActions.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at platform.receiverActions.requestProcedures.business.RequestProcessing$$$view14.processRequest(Unknown Source) [receiverActions.jar:]
    at comm.http.RestHttpServlet.handleRequest(RestHttpServlet.java:221)
    at comm.http.RestHttpServlet.handlePostRequest(RestHttpServlet.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:102) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource$1.parse(JAXBSource.java:222) [jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    ... 117 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:265)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:657)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:597)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:700)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:597)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:652)
    ... 134 more
```

Related: [Convert LinkedHashMap<String,String> to an object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105687/convert-linkedhashmapstring-string-to-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105687/convert-linkedhashmapstring-string-to-an-object-in-java

Comment: Are you getting the error in request validation or response validation? (I am confused because if it was an error in the request validation it should not have hit your POST service method) or am i missing something?

Comment: I get it in Request validation. Actually the request is validated after it lands on the server.

Comment: Do you mind adding the complete stack trace . Usually the marshaller is used to convert object to xml or json (unmarshaller is used to convert json/xml to object). So I am curious to know how and who is triggering your validation

Comment: Also did you try testing it with a Response.ok (instead of returning a String) (like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687271/jax-rs-how-to-return-json-and-http-status-code-together) ..I still suspect the marshaller is trying to convert your string to  json

Comment: @Rohit: I have added the server logs. Check the edit to the question

Comment: ok -I can only guess that your request validator (which I presume to be your custom framework or application code) is not correctly determining if the content type is xml or json (and validate accordingly). To me it seems that it is trying to parse and validate your json against an XSD which is bound to fail if your input is json. Check if your common.utils.XmlMapper is called correctly (it should be invoked only for xml response) . It is also very odd to perform request validation after you return the response and exit the controller.

Comment: It seems you have 2 issues 1) The filter or interceptor that triggers your business rules (which in turn validates your request) is not setup correctly i.e. it is getting invoked after your exit the controller 2) the  RequestValidationBean is not able to detect your json input and is validating it as xml

Comment: @Rohit: The issue got resolved after using Jackson library in client too than use JAXB for my conversion to json from POJO. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after I used jackson library in client too for converting POJO to json rather than JAXB.

**Client code** now:

```
 ContentInstance cont = new ContentInstance();
 cont.setContent("Sid");
 cont.setStateTag(BigInteger.ONE);
 cont.setContentSize(BigInteger.TEN);

 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
 om.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());

        try {
            System.out.print("OBJECT MAPPER:---> JSON STRING" + om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(cont));
            jsonContent = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(cont);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The issue was my `content` parameter in my POJO was of type `Object` and JAXB was making a `LinkedHashMap` after converting to json, which was not provided in the JAXB context (thus the error). 
Now, using `ObjectMapper`, `content` is corrrectly converted to Json.

Ex:
Earlier using JAXB `content` was converted to a `LinkedaHashMap`

```
content: {"type":"String", "value":"Sid"}
```

Using Jackson `ObjectMapper`:

`{content: "Sid"}`

Comment: Would you be able to help my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171947/jaxb-and-linkedhashmap-xml-serialization-failure

I am having the same issue but instead of serializing to JSON I am trying to serialize to XML. Thanks!

Comment: @Yaz: You could also use jackson for XML with `jackson-dataformat-xml jar` if that works for your case

Comment: The question was answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your environment set up, you are using Jackson-JAXB framework to marshal and unmarshal data-objects. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Try below these 2 options first separately and then perhaps together:

1. Change the type of input parameter in handlePostRequest method to String:

> public String handlePostRequest(String resource) {
>
> ```
> System.out.println("\nINSIDE HANDLE POST: " + resource);
> }
> ```

Please let me know if it runs and what it prints. I suspect framework is trying to map object type to LinkedHashMap which is default mapping.

2. Modify the annotation tags with following:

   @POST

   ```
   @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})

   @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
   ```