# JAXB and LinkedHashMap: XML serialization failure

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jaxb

I am having a similar issue that's been discussed here: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950587/com-sun-istack-saxexception2-class-java-util-linkedhashmap-nor-any-of-its-super)

Basically: using JAXB, I want to serialize a 'complex' POJO that's been generated by XJC (and xsd schemas) to XML but the conversion fails with the error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

The POJO is complex in the sense that it has fields with type `List<Object>` that in runtime gets instantiated to a `List<LinkedHashMap<Category>>`. Thus it appears that JAXB does not know how to convert this to XML.

When I add LinkedHashMap.class to the JAXB Context, the serialization succeeds but the xml is incomplete:

`<response>
            <Common Version="1.1" Lang="EN">
                <Option xsi:type="linkedHashMap"/>
            </Common>
</response>`

The `<Common>` node is incomplete because it is serializing `Option` but not `Category`.

Is this a known issue with JAXB? That it doesn't support serialization of LinkedHashMap data types?

Thank you.

Comment: You could also use jackson for XML with `jackson-dataformat-xml jar` if that works for your case

Comment: Thank you @SiddarthTrikha. I will try it but I believe my issue is one of the limitations that they list: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml